# What's the difference between href and path in Url.parse() object?

Tags: node.js

I have the following code written in NodeJS:

```
var Url = require("url");

// create server ... req, res

var queryData = Url.parse(req.url, true);
console.log(queryData);

// listen (...)
```

For the url from browser `/test?param1=val1` the `queryData` is an object like this:

```
{ protocol: null,
  slashes: null,
  auth: null,
  host: null,
  port: null,
  hostname: null,
  hash: null,
  search: '?param1=val1',
  query: { param1: 'val1' },
  pathname: '/test',
  path: '/test?param1=val1',
  href: '/test?param1=val1' }
```

What's is the difference between `path` and `href` fields from parsed url object?

Is there any case when they are **not** the same?

---

EDIT: I see that in the documentation the `href` is  "`The full URL that was originally parsed. Both the protocol and host are lowercased.`".

> Example: 'http://user:pass@host.com:8080/p/a/t/h?query=string#hash'

Why I don't get `href` like this? If I add a `#hash` to the url the `href` from the object is **not changed**.

Comment: http://nodejs.org/api/url.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/url.html):

> href: The full URL that was originally parsed. Both the protocol and
>   host are lowercased. Example:
>   'http://user:pass@host.com:8080/p/a/t/h?query=string#hash'
>
> path: Concatenation of pathname and search. Example:
>   '/p/a/t/h?query=string'

Comment: I updated my question. Why the `#hash` doesn't appear in the `href` field from the object?

Comment: The `hash` part of a url is not sent to the server when requesting a url via a browser. you can see that by inspecting your `req.url` source parameter.